# Want to declare a value to a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string

I am currently making a currency converter in VB.NET, but there is a little obstacle. The currency I want to convert is selected in the combobox.

Now it kinda looks like this:

```
    If Combobox1.Text = "USD" Then
        USD1.Text = Amount.Text * (USD / USD)
        EUR1.Text = Amount.Text * (USD / EUR)
        GBP1.Text = Amount.Text * (USD / GBP)
        NOK1.Text = Amount.Text * (USD / NOK)
    End If
    If Combobox1.Text = "EUR" Then
        USD1.Text = Amount.Text * (EUR / USD)
        EUR1.Text = Amount.Text * (EUR / EUR)
        GBP1.Text = Amount.Text * (EUR / GBP)
        NOK1.Text = Amount.Text * (EUR / NOK)
    End If
```

But I want it to look more like this:

```
    USD1.Text = Amount * (SelectedExch / USD)
    EUR1.Text = Amount * (SelectedExch / EUR)
```

So any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I've done some research and experimenting, and here is my code currently:

```
Private Sub Textbox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Amount.TextChanged
    Dim USD = My.Settings.USD
    Dim EUR = My.Settings.EUR
    Dim GBP = My.Settings.GBP
    Dim NOK = My.Settings.NOK
    Dim value, value2 As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(Amount.Text, value) Then
        USD1.Text = ""
        EUR1.Text = ""
        GBP1.Text = ""
        NOK1.Text = ""
        Return
    End If
    Select Case Currency.Text
        Case "USD"
            value2 = USD
        Case "EUR"
            value2 = EUR
        Case "GBP"
            value2 = GBP
        Case "NOK"
            value2 = NOK
    End Select
    value2 *= value
    USD1.Text = Math.Round((value2 / USD), 1)
    EUR1.Text = Math.Round((value2 / EUR), 1)
    GBP1.Text = Math.Round((value2 / GBP), 1)
    NOK1.Text = Math.Round((value2 / NOK), 1)
End Sub
```

I can't say I understand everything in the code. Do you see any room for improvement? I later want to give the user option to add currencies

Answer (score 0):

Here's perhaps a slightly more elegant way to do this

```
Public Class Form1

   Private Enum CurrencyTypes
       USD
       EUR
       GBP
       NOK
   End Enum

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
                                                            Handles MyBase.Load
       ComboBox1.DataSource = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(CurrencyTypes))
   End Sub

   Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                           Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
       Dim source As CurrencyTypes = [Enum].Parse(GetType(CurrencyTypes), _
                                                  ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
       UpdateConversion(source)
   End Sub

   Private Sub UpdateConversion(ByVal sourceCurrency As CurrencyTypes)
       USD1.Text = ConvertCurrency(sourceCurrency, CurrencyTypes.USD).ToString()
       EUR1.Text = ConvertCurrency(sourceCurrency, CurrencyTypes.EUR).ToString()
       GBP1.Text = ConvertCurrency(sourceCurrency, CurrencyTypes.GBP).ToString()
       NOK1.Text = ConvertCurrency(sourceCurrency, CurrencyTypes.NOK).ToString()
   End Sub

   Private Function ConvertCurrency(ByVal fromType As CurrencyTypes, _
                                          toType As CurrencyTypes) As Decimal
        'do conversion
   End Function

End Class
```

You haven't shown any implementation details of how you are getting your conversion values.  You seem to be showing math on strings, which doesn't make any sense - if you've got `Option Strict` turned off, then for the love of all things good please turn it ON.  In any case, I haven't filled in the `ConvertCurrency` function, but presumably you are sourcing the exchange values from somewhere.  All that function needs to do is to relate a conversion value to a `CurrencyTypes` enum type.  If you don't know how to do this, it's probably a good subject for another question.

Comment: Well, the currency values is only written in manually and can be edited by the user. I want the program to get rates from an internet resource later, but I currently don't know how to do it. I've edited the code in the top post if you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim lstExchangeRates As New List(Of ExchangeRate)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim excExchangeRate As ExchangeRate

        excExchangeRate = New ExchangeRate With {.RateName = "USD", .Rate = 1}
        lstExchangeRates.Add(excExchangeRate)

        excExchangeRate = New ExchangeRate With {.RateName = "EUR", .Rate = 1.2}
        lstExchangeRates.Add(excExchangeRate)

        excExchangeRate = New ExchangeRate With {.RateName = "GBP", .Rate = 0.5}
        lstExchangeRates.Add(excExchangeRate)

        excExchangeRate = New ExchangeRate With {.RateName = "NOK", .Rate = 1.5}
        lstExchangeRates.Add(excExchangeRate)

        ComboBox1.DataSource = lstExchangeRates
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "RateName"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Rate"

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        CalculateValues()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Amount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Amount.TextChanged
        CalculateValues()

    End Sub

    Private Sub CalculateValues()

        If Amount.Text = "" Then Exit Sub

        For Each ExchangeRateItem As ExchangeRate In lstExchangeRates

            Dim txtExchangeRate As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls(ExchangeRateItem.RateName & "1"), TextBox)

            txtExchangeRate.Text = CDbl(Amount.Text) * (ComboBox1.SelectedValue / (From ExchangeRates As ExchangeRate In lstExchangeRates
                                            Where ExchangeRates.RateName = ExchangeRateItem.RateName
                                            Select ExchangeRates.Rate).FirstOrDefault)

        Next

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ExchangeRate

    Public Property RateName As String
    Public Property Rate As Double

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not the simplest way, with the construction of Dictionary in Form Load:

```
Dim Currencies as New Dictionary(Of String, Double)
Currencies.Add("USD", [Value of USD])
Currencies.Add("EUR", [Value of EUR])
...
```

And calling just like:

```
Dim SelectedExch as Double = Currencies(Combobox1.Text)
USD1.Text = Amount.Text * (SelectedExch / USD)
EUR1.Text = Amount.Text * (SelectedExch / EUR)
GBP1.Text = Amount.Text * (SelectedExch / GBP)
NOK1.Text = Amount.Text * (SelectedExch / NOK)
```